# mysql update is so slow - is there any faster way to update data?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have to update 2M*2rows in a mysql database.

All the information is in a file, that I process with php.
I get the information in a array, and then push it in the database using

```
UPDATE processed 
SET number1=$row[1], number2=$row[2], timestamp=unix_timestamp()
where match (id) against ('\"$id\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 1
```

That's working - but it takes soo long...

I have an index (primary) on (id).

I have tried to use something else than (id) that's on a fulltext index (i'm using Myisam) - it's even slower.

As my database is pretty big, and mysql has to go through everything to find the right line to update, it takes a few seconds per update.. which means a few days to process my update!

Is there any faster way to do that?
If I switch to innodb will that be faster? (Even if it's not I guess it can be cool at during the update, my whole table won't be locked).

As number1 & number2 are numbers, I though about grouping all the (id) that have to be updated to the same number - would that be faster?

Is there a way to tune mysqld so that number1, number2 & id colums would stay in RAM, making it faster to access / update?

Any idea is welcome, as I'm totally lost... :)

edit: adding an example code so that you can understand my situation:

```
foreach ($data_rows as $rows) {
  $row=explode(":", $rows);  // $row[0] info
                             // $row[1] new number1
                             // $row[2] new number2

 $query = $db->query("select * from processed where match (info) against ('\"$info\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 1");

   while ($line = $query->fetch_object())
 {
   $data[$line->hash]['number1']=$line->number1;
   $data[$line->hash]['number2']=$line->number2;
   $id=$line->id;
  }

  if (is_array($data[$info]))       {  // Check if we have this one in the database.
    // If the number is correct, no need to update.
     if (($data[$info]['number1'] != $row[1]) && ($data[$info]['number2'] != $row[2])) {
 $db->query("UPDATE processed SET number1=$row[1], number2=$row[2], timestamp=unix_timestamp() where id=$id");
print "updated - $info - $row[1] - $row[2]\n";
                                               }
                    }
else    {
print "$info not in database\n";
    }
                }
```

shema:

```
CREATE TABLE `processed` (
  `id` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` int(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` text,
  `category` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `subcat` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `number1` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `number2` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text,
  `hash` text,
  `url` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1328365 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

edit again:

`ANALYZE TABLE processed;` did help a lot in improving the time of my `UPDATEs`. (fresh indexes!)

Will add my data in another table & join update anyway :)

Comment: 1. innodb does not support fulltext. 2. Why you set `id` field as part of the fulltext column ? (should it be a normal integer field?)

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your indexes if that's taking a long time. Please post your table definition. (The output of DESCRIBE processed)

Comment: @Cfreak: `+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(30)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| number1          | int(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| number2          | int(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment          | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hash             | text     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |`

Comment: @ajreal: i know, but i don't need fulltext, i did set up sphinx - for id because i just tried with the fulltext value and did just change 'id' then

Comment: @John_Bob don't do a BIG select then while loop update the single match row. Is slow. Could this be something solved using JOIN? Without both the source and targeted table schema if hard to know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Its unclear why you are doing a plain full text search against an integer? Why not just an "UPDATE ... WHERE id = $id". Also you can get rid of the LIMIT 1, in some cases that confuses MySQL.

Comment: @Cody it's just because i did some testing with a fulltext before and didn't remove it. removed though.. :)

Comment: @ajreal - just added more information. ask if you need more. I tried with a big select & with a little select (like in the example) - it's the same as it's `UPDATE` that's slow (and locking my whole table :/) - I don't understand why `UPDATE` is so slower than `SELECT`...

Comment: @John_Bog I'm out, We need the schema, We are not interested on your PHP update (cause that part is slow). FYI, update=write to disk, select=read from disk

Comment: @ajreal: added the schema. i don't think that it's slow because of PHP, but because of UPDATE - I know that updite=write & select=read but what makes UPDATE so slow? Isn't it the time needed to figure out where to write? (ie some kind of select..)

Comment: because of your looping in php . if you have 10000 record it will write 10000 times to disk . do  join ?

Comment: yep. but why is `UPDATE` waay slower than `DELETE` & `INSERT` for example?

Comment: @John_Bob Delete is always faster. While for INSERT is depending on how many insert command you have been issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing 2M*2 `UPDATE` commands. That does take a while...

I would advise you to dump the file contents into a temp table and then running a single `UPDATE` command.

**Update**

Here is how you'd run a single joined `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE processed 
inner join DumpTable on processed.id = DumpTable.id
SET number1=DumpTable.value1 , number2=DumpTable.value2, timestamp=unix_timestamp()
```

Comment: If I dump my whole file in a database, how will I then be able to run a single `UPDATE` command that will add everything at the right place?

Comment: Thanks. Will try that. It sounds like a good option to do things more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Well a) You should always be sanitizing your data -

```
sprintf("UPDATE processed 
         SET number1=%d, number2=%d, timestamp=unix_timestamp() 
         WHERE match (id) 
         AGAINST ('%d' $id IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 1",
         mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]),
         mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]),
         mysql_real_escape_string($id)
);
```

Also if you switch to InnoDB it may be slightly faster, however, it is a better option for a lot of people as you do not lock the whole table you are working on for every UPDATE you do, you only lock the row which you are updating.

So it is most definatly something to think about, please read the following link : http://www.kavoir.com/2009/09/mysql-engines-innodb-vs-myisam-a-comparison-of-pros-and-cons.html

Comment: It's better to `mysql_real_escape_string` everything even if it has already by escaped in the php code? Regarding InnoDB it sounds interesting as it seems that in my situation it can't hurt (if I stop using Fulltext search)

Comment: I personally would always mysql_real_escape_string everything which I push to the database or even pull from the database. I would also suggest creating a backup of your database, creating a new one as InnoDB and giving it a try.

What harm can It do? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html

750,000qps might speed thing up a bit.

Comment: Will check this article. Thanks